# C# WebBrowser Page Scrolling From Code

Tags: c#, scroll, browser

I'm trying to scroll a website (x and y) without scrollbar. I tryed a lot of codes, but it doesn't work. Can you help me please?

Comment: "I tryed a lot", such as ?

Comment: I tryed a lot of script. Sorry I'm not english D:

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element

Comment: @ottovolante321 - He means show us source code. (Either to be able to correct your errors or to show us some effort.) "Tried a lot of codes." - could mean you have used them in a wrong manner, and "it doesn't work" could mean lots of things and unusable without error message, exception message or error code.

Comment: Exactly, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I know I know but please tell me how to execute javascript code into a webbrowser by using C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found a method to do that.

```
        HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        HtmlElement s = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
        s.SetAttribute("text", "function functionName() { /* Code to Execute in JS */ }");
        head.AppendChild(s);
        webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("functionName");
```

Remember to execute this code after about five second that the website correctly load. A special thank to Steven Dall

Answer (score 0):

To My Knowledge you cannot do this from C# side.

You can however run something in javascript like

```
window.scrollTo(xPos,yPos);
```

and if you really want to do this from C#, I'd suggest looking into registering scripts to run on the client, Although this can get messy fast. As Comments are suggesting it is hard to help you on your exact problem because we would need to see some code for what you have tried and where you problem domain lies.

Comment: I'm not at home now. But I will try it. Thank you very match. ☺

Comment: There is a C# code to execute java script code in a Web browser?